# submitting django crispy form with file field and some other text fields using fetch and then

Tags: django, ajax, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to submit my crispy form using fetch and then methods to django backend. All my fields are submitting to the server. but files are shown as empty fields in the server.
**below, is my front end from**

```
 {{ photo.media }}
            <form action="" method="post" class="form my-4 px-2" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="photo_form"
                onsubmit="">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{photo|crispy}}
                <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
            </form>
```

**Here is the ajax request I made**

```
           <script>
                const photoForm = document.querySelector('#photo_form');

                console.log(photoForm.values);

                photoForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
                    event.preventDefault();

                    const photoFormData = new FormData(photoForm);

                    photoFormData.forEach((value, key) => {
                        console.log(key + ': ' + value);
                    });

                    fetch("{% url 'add_photo' %}", {
                        method: 'POST',
                        body: photoFormData,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                    })
                        .then((response) => response.json())
                        .then((data) => {

                            console.log(data);

                            if (data.result == 'success') {
                                $('.modal-body').html('Form submission was successful!');
                                $('#modal-dialog').modal('show');
                                photoForm.reset();

                            } else {

                                $('.modal-body').html('There was an error with the form submission.');
                                $('#modal-dialog').modal('show');
                            }

                        });
                });

            </script>
```

**Below, is the model I Made**

```
class Photos(models.Model):
    photo_title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    photo_description = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    photo_date = models.DateField(blank=False)
    photo_location = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    photo_file = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos', blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.photo_title
```

**Below, is the view function**

```
""" ajax add photo event to home wall """


def add_photo(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        response_data = {}
        photoForm = UploadPhotosForm(request.POST)
        print(photoForm.is_valid())
        print(photoForm.errors)
        if photoForm.is_valid():
            photoForm.save()
            response_data['result'] = 'success'
            print(response_data)
            return HttpResponse(
                JsonResponse(response_data),
            )
    else:
        response_data['result'] = 'error'
        print(photoForm.errors)
        return HttpResponse(
            JsonResponse(response_data),
        )
```

While I tried to figure out the problem, I got these outputs

**from client side**

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken: xDJ7qlvfOgaPta6VXkIH03QlT1AybEQ46xcC2ri09MO4F7DbBPGbeNehMrJa3Rjy
(index):141 photo_title: sadfsf
(index):141 photo_description: sfsfse
(index):141 photo_date: 2022-12-22
(index):141 photo_location: adsafd
(index):141 photo_file: [object File]
(index):144 

POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/manager/add/photo/ 500 (Internal Server Error)
(anonymous) @ (index):144
VM750:1 
        
       Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ (index):149
```

**from server side**

```
False
<ul class="errorlist"><li>photo_file<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
<ul class="errorlist"><li>photo_file<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
[21/Dec/2022 15:09:10] "POST /manager/add/photo/ HTTP/1.1" 200 19
```

can someone help me out to figure out the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `post` method, change to:

```
photoForm = UploadPhotosForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
```